# Zig Zag Product's

Tags: graph-theory

Hi I read this paper about the Zig Zag Product's (page 73-74)

http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~nati/PAPERS/expander_survey.pdf

and I encounter this equation. but I did not understand why this is true.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice how $f^\perp$ and $f^\parallel$ are orthogonal to each other. Then apply the Pythagorean theorem for Hilbert spaces.

Comment: I know that I can apply the Pythagorean theorem for Hilbert spaces but I do not understand how I get to the final equation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Inner_product_spaces The second equation in Inner Product spaces is giving you the answer. It is literally the same thing, as $f = f^\parallel + f^\perp$